# Access Enum translated with J2objc in Swift

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, swift, j2objc

I use J2objc to translate Java to Objective-C. This code I use with a bridging header to make it available in Swift. Here is a Java Enum I translated:

```
public enum BTestType {

  Type1, Type2, Type3;

}
```

In Objective-C I get the following header file (I skip the module file):

```
#ifndef _BISBTestType_H_
#define _BISBTestType_H_

#include "J2ObjC_header.h"
#include "java/lang/Enum.h"

typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, BISBTestType) {
  BISBTestType_Type1 = 0,
  BISBTestType_Type2 = 1,
  BISBTestType_Type3 = 2,
};

@interface BISBTestTypeEnum : JavaLangEnum < NSCopying >

#pragma mark Package-Private

+ (IOSObjectArray *)values;
FOUNDATION_EXPORT IOSObjectArray *BISBTestTypeEnum_values();

+ (BISBTestTypeEnum *)valueOfWithNSString:(NSString *)name;
FOUNDATION_EXPORT BISBTestTypeEnum *BISBTestTypeEnum_valueOfWithNSString_(NSString *name);

- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone;

@end

J2OBJC_STATIC_INIT(BISBTestTypeEnum)

FOUNDATION_EXPORT BISBTestTypeEnum *BISBTestTypeEnum_values_[];

#define BISBTestTypeEnum_Type1 BISBTestTypeEnum_values_[BISBTestType_Type1]
J2OBJC_ENUM_CONSTANT_GETTER(BISBTestTypeEnum, Type1)

#define BISBTestTypeEnum_Type2 BISBTestTypeEnum_values_[BISBTestType_Type2]
J2OBJC_ENUM_CONSTANT_GETTER(BISBTestTypeEnum, Type2)

#define BISBTestTypeEnum_Type3 BISBTestTypeEnum_values_[BISBTestType_Type3]
J2OBJC_ENUM_CONSTANT_GETTER(BISBTestTypeEnum, Type3)

J2OBJC_TYPE_LITERAL_HEADER(BISBTestTypeEnum)

typedef BISBTestTypeEnum BISTestTypeEnum;

#endif // _BISBTestType_H_
```

To access an enum in Swift I had to call the following:

```
 var r:BISBTestTypeEnum = BISBTestTypeEnum.values().objectAtIndex(BISBTestType.Type1.rawValue) as! BISBTestTypeEnum
```

**Is there a simpler way of accessing the objective-c enums in Swift?**

Comment: have you tried `var r:BISBTestType = .BISBTestType_Type1`?

Comment: @MariusSerban No it does not work this way. Error: Could not find member 'BISBTestType'

Comment: The problem is that I need the type ``BISBTestTypeEnum``instead of ``BISBTestType``.

Answer (score 2):

There is a more simple way of doing this. Add the `--static-accessor-methods` flag and then you can access like:

```
var r:BISBTestTypeEnum = BISBTestTypeEnum.Type1()
```

Answer (score 0):

For a simpler way of accessing the enum you could extend the the `BISBTestTypeEnum` class and implement a convenience class method:

```
extension BISBTestTypeEnum {
    class func withValue(value: BISBTestType) -> BISBTestTypeEnum {
        return BISBTestTypeEnum.values().objectAtIndex(value.rawValue) as! BISBTestTypeEnum
    }
}
```

And then you can use:

```
var r = BISBTestTypeEnum.withValue(BISBTestType.Type1)
```

Comment: The problem is that I have to do it for each Enum. There should be a combined solution.

Answer (score -1):

It appears that you can use the method `BISBTestTypeEnum_get_Type2()` (derived from the `J2OBJC_ENUM_CONSTANT_GETTER(BISBTestTypeEnum, Type2)` macro), but though this passes compilation it fails at link time.

Comment: So how does this help if it fails at link time?